# How to make a pure border design responsive?

Tags: html, css, responsive

I found this design on codepen made purely of borders, how should I go about making it responsive?

Using width % doesn't seem to work here, neither does setting max width or creating div containers.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.triangle,
.triangle--1,
.triangle--2,
.triangle--3,
.triangle--4,
.triangle--5 {
  border-right-color: transparent;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  border-left-color: transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 600px 600px 0;
  content: "";
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  -moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
  -moz-border-left-colors: none;
  -moz-border-right-colors: none;
  -moz-border-top-colors: none;
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(-12px 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4));
  filter: drop-shadow(-12px 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4));
}

.triangle--1 {
  border-top-color: #0151a3;
  top: -60px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.triangle--2 {
  border-top-color: #025ebc;
  top: -120px;
  z-index: 3;
}

.triangle--3 {
  border-top-color: #026bd5;
  top: -180px;
  z-index: 4;
}

.triangle--4 {
  border-top-color: #0277ee;
  top: -240px;
  z-index: 5;
}

.triangle--5 {
  border-top-color: #0d84fd;
  top: -300px;
  z-index: 6;
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle--1"></div>
<div class="triangle--2"></div>
<div class="triangle--3"></div>
<div class="triangle--4"></div>
<div class="triangle--5"></div>
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here read how to create a [mcve] example and also check [ask] so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Comment: You didn't post the HTML, this is more of a request than a question. Try something like Upwork instead?

Comment: <div class="triangle--1"></div>

<div class="triangle--2"></div>

<div class="triangle--3"></div>

<div class="triangle--4"></div>

<div class="triangle--5"></div>

In case if you want everything
https://codepen.io/snhasani/pen/FoeBK%20

Comment: Try wording your question better next time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `width: 50vw` makes something 50% of the viewport's width.

In this case, it's helpful for borders as borders does not accept 50% as a valid input.

Changing `border-width: 600px 600px 0;` to `border-width: 50vw 50vw 0;` should make it horizontally responsive.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.triangle,
.triangle--1,
.triangle--2,
.triangle--3,
.triangle--4,
.triangle--5 {
  border-right-color: transparent;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  border-left-color: transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 50vw 50vw 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  content: "";
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  -moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
  -moz-border-left-colors: none;
  -moz-border-right-colors: none;
  -moz-border-top-colors: none;
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(-12px 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4));
  filter: drop-shadow(-12px 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4));
}

.triangle--1 {
  border-top-color: #0151a3;
  top: -60px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.triangle--2 {
  border-top-color: #025ebc;
  top: -120px;
  z-index: 3;
}

.triangle--3 {
  border-top-color: #026bd5;
  top: -180px;
  z-index: 4;
}

.triangle--4 {
  border-top-color: #0277ee;
  top: -240px;
  z-index: 5;
}

.triangle--5 {
  border-top-color: #0d84fd;
  top: -300px;
  z-index: 6;
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle--1"></div>
<div class="triangle--2"></div>
<div class="triangle--3"></div>
<div class="triangle--4"></div>
<div class="triangle--5"></div>
```